# Source of strange sessions

Tags: php, session-management

I stumbled upon some strange entries in our PHP sessions, they look like this:

`PHPREDIS_SESSION:${9923XXXXX+99XXXXXX}` (<- I have changed some digits to 'X')

`PHPREDIS_SESSION:http://hitbXXXXXXXXXXX.bxss.me/` (<- I have changed some letters to 'X')

Presumably, someone is trying something.

How do these entries get injected?

What are the dangers of having them present?

Comment: This is very little information to say something useful. It appears you're storing  sessions in Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Anything coming from the client-side can be manipulated by the client. There are numerous tools that allow people to see and modify data send back to your server. Burp Suite and OWASP Zap are a couple of good examples.

People can use these tools for QA testing, and they are also used to probe applications and services for weaknesses. And that looks like that might be what's going on here.

Every server and every service exposed to the Internet will experience constant and unrelenting probes like this. That is why even the "smallest" app needs to be coded and managed securely. If there is a weakness, someone will eventually find it, and it's all automated, so it costs people nothing to try.

Comment: Sure, but how do the client get to generate the session-'id'?

Comment: You send the session identifier to the client, yes? And the client sends it back? Take a look at Burp Suite to see how one can manipulate data on the client side.

Comment: I am concerned that clients can generate session identifiers and then inject them into my session store (redis in this case), that should not happen?

Comment: "that should not happen" -- I've tried to explain how that happens and how easily that happens. And how much you are to expect it. You need to design your server to handle it.

Comment: "How do these entries get injected?" -- client manipulated the data before sending back. "What are the dangers of having them present?" -- that depends on the weaknesses of your server.